# What does the "Eliminating The Impossible" item set really do (if it does anything at all)?

Tags: team-fortress-2

So a new update brought us the "Nine Pipe Problem" and the wiki tells me that if you equip the "Private Eye" and the "Nine Pipe Problem" you complete the "[Eliminating The Impossible"](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Item_sets#Eliminating_The_Impossible) item set which can reduce mystery solving by up to 88%"

What does this really do?

Comment: I assume it's a joke, but don't have proof

Comment: Well, for what it's worth, it's a Sherlock Holmes reference: **"[W]hen you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth[.]"**  He also at one point categorized the difficulty of a problem by how many pipes he'd have to smoke to solve it (which is probably where "Nine Pipe Problem" comes from)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This attribute used to be a joke up until the [June 20, 2012 Patch](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/June_20,_2012_Patch). Now you can use it to "solve" the mistery of the six crafting ingredients.

- [Goldfish](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Goldfish): "Think of the"
- [Pocket lint](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Pocket_Lint): "...the... which..."
- [Cheese wheel](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Cheese_Wheel): "may go on... the hidden wickedness..."
- [Banana peel](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Banana_Peel): "...may go on..."
- [Barn door plank](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Barn_Door_Plank): "...year in, year out..."
- [Damaged capacitator](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Damaged_Capacitor): "the deeds of hellish cruelty and none the wiser"
- [Secret diary](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Secret_Diary): "the deeds of hellish cruelty and none the wiser"

Please note the actual item descriptions are only a random selection of letters from each description - each user having a different selection. The above is what you get by plugging the holes together.

What follows, instead, is what you get from all of the above.

> [image]
>
> <sup>[source](http://www.reddit.com/r/tf2/comments/vcsni/arg_central/)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> When combined with the other items added in the [June 20, 2012 Patch](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/June_20,_2012_Patch), the full quote reads:
>
> *Think of the deeds of hellish cruelty, the hidden wickedness which may go on, year in, year out, in such places, and none the wiser.*
>
> <sup>[source](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Secret_Diary#Trivia)</sup>

Comment: I solved the mystery: when you combine that descriptions you get: _Think of the deeds of hellish cruelty, the hidden wickedness which may go on, year in, year out, in such places, and none the wiser._ It's another quote of Sherlock Holmes

Answer (score 6):

Nothing... at the moment.

According to the item schema, mystery solving is an *actual* attribute, but it would appear to have no effect in game. Obviously, it's not clear at this point, but a future update might actually make the attribute do something.

```
"name": "mystery solving time decrease",
"defindex": 391,
"attribute_class": "mystery_solving_time_decrease",
"min_value": 0.000000,
"max_value": 1.000000,
"description_string": "Reduces mystery solving time by up to %s1%",
"description_format": "value_is_percentage",
"effect_type": "positive",
"hidden": false,
"stored_as_integer": false
```

No item sets since Australian Christmas have had effects that change the attributes of weaponry/damage resistance, so it would be odd for Valve to release a new item set with beneficial stats, suggesting that it may just be a joke attribute, and part of the theme of the item set.

As the TF2 wiki [also notes](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Nine-Pipe_Problem#Trivia):

> The item is a reference to Sir Arthur Conan Doyle's fictional detective Sherlock Holmes. Specifically, it alludes to the phrase "three pipe problem" introduced in the short story The Red-Headed League, and refers to the amount of tobacco needed to ponder over and deduce the solution to a particular puzzle.

which further suggests it could just be part of the item set theme.

Comment: It isn't a joke, it gives the new items a new description according to the wiki